# Changing Strings through a function in C

Tags: c, string

Disclaimer: The code below is taken from Derek Banas off youtube, I just don't understand why it works.

In the code below the entire string is changed even though the string isn't the same size. I do not understand how the entire string is changed when the for loop does not go through all the indexes however. For example, if oldString was of length 10, and newString was of size 5, the for loop below would change indexes 0 to 4 on oldString (as far as I can tell,) but the rest of the String is somehow deleted and I am not sure how. I have tested the code myself and it does work.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void editMessageSent(char* message, int size){
    char newMessage[] = "New Message";
    if(size > sizeof(newMessage)){
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(newMessage); i++){
            message[i] = newMessage[i];
        } 
    } else {
        printf("New Message is too big\n\n");
    }
}
void main(){
    // Passing a String to a Function ----
    char randomMessage[] = "Edit my function";
    printf("Old Message: %s \n\n",
        randomMessage);
    editMessageSent(randomMessage, 
        sizeof(randomMessage));
    printf("New Message: %s \n\n",
        randomMessage);
    }
```

Comment: `newMessage` contains an implicit `\0` to terminate the string constant. Examine the result of `sizeof(newMessage)` (or step through the loop in the debugger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the new string is shorter, the null terminater `'\0'` is copied into the old string as well.

And after `editMessageSent`, for example, if the new string is `"hello"`:

```
"Edit my function"  ->  "hello\0y function"
```

`"%s"` in `printf` outputs the string until the first `'\0'`.

Comment: Thank you. So the size of the string stays the same, would there be a way to actually change the size so it's not using extra space? (as minor as it may seem). Or would you actually have to create a new string for that?

Comment: `randomMessage` is an array, its size is constant.

Comment: @user120920 If the string had been obtained from malloc, realloc could be used to give back the extra space. But in this code its an array of 17 chars (sizeof("Edit my function") == 17) allocated at compile time, and that can't be changed.